# PL/SQL Oracle 11g Looping

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am having trouble solve.  I am suppose to be getting a record every time there is a change to an account in our data warehouse, but I am only receiving one.  The table below is a sample of what I am working with.

```
Row     Acct1   Acct2   Date        Total_Reissued  Reissue_Per_Day
1       A        1      1/1/2016    2               2
2       A        1      1/2/2016    3               1
3       A        1      1/3/2016    5               2
4       A        1      1/4/2016    6               1

1       B       3       1/1/2016    1               1
2       B       3       1/2/2016    2               1
1       B       4       1/1/2016    1               1
2       B       4       1/2/2016    2               1
```

The Reissued Column is a running total.  For Acct A on 1/1/2016 there were 2 reissues, then On 1/2/2016 there was 1 more making a total of 3.  My problem is calculating the actual number of reissues per day.

Comment: Please edit your question to include additional information. As it reads now I don't understand how to get from what you show in the "Reissued" column to what you've shown in the "Results I want" column.  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `lag()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions082.htm) to peek back at the previous row; assuming that 'previous' is the last date you saw for the acct1/acct2 combination you can do:

```
select row_number() over (partition by acct1, acct2 order by dt) as row_num,
  acct1, acct2, dt, total_reissued,
  total_reissued - nvl(lag(total_reissued)
    over (partition by acct1, acct2 order by dt), 0) as reissue_per_day
from your_table;

   ROW_NUM A      ACCT2 DT         TOTAL_REISSUED REISSUE_PER_DAY
---------- - ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------------
         1 A          1 2016-01-01              2               2
         2 A          1 2016-01-02              3               1
         3 A          1 2016-01-03              5               2
         4 A          1 2016-01-04              6               1
         1 B          3 2016-01-01              1               1
         2 B          3 2016-01-02              2               1
         1 B          4 2016-01-01              1               1
         2 B          4 2016-01-02              2               1
```

I'm not sure if your 'row' column actually exists, or is required, or was just to illustrate your data. I've generated it anyway, in case you need it.

The main bit of interest is:

```
lag(total_reissued) over (partition by acct1, acct2 order by dt)
```

which finds the previous date's value (using `dt` as a column name, since `date` isn't a valid name). That then has an `nvl()` wrapper so the first row sees a dummy value of zero instead of null. And then that is subtracted from the current row's value to get the difference.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!  Thank you!